# Linux Kernel write() and read() function

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Hello I need some help with my code for school.

The read function should never `return 0` so Teacher told us to use `wait_event_interruptible`.

My problem is when I want to try it using (for exmaple) commands in console :

```
echo 1234 > ringdev # my character device
echo 5 > ringdev 
cat ringdev
```

I only get a result: `5`.

I want to get a result:

`1234
5`.

The global variables:

```
 static char ringdev_buf[4096];
 static size_t ringdev_len;
```

Read function:

```
static ssize_t ringdev_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count,
        loff_t *off)
{      
    ssize_t ret = 0;
    while(1) {
        wait_event_interruptible(head,ringdev_len!=0);
        mutex_lock(&ringdev_lock);
        if(ringdev_len!=0) {
            ret = -EFAULT;
            if (copy_to_user(buf, ringdev_buf,ringdev_len)) { // I was trying everything in the ringdev_len position. 
                ret = ringdev_len;
                goto out_unlock;
            }
        }
        mutex_unlock(&ringdev_lock);
    }
    out_unlock:
    mutex_unlock(&ringdev_lock);
    return ret;
}
```

I was trying to put any value in count in function `copy_to_user(buf, ringdev_buf,count)` but the result was always the same.

```
static ssize_t ringdev_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf,
        size_t count, loff_t *off)
{
    ssize_t ret=0;
    mutex_lock(&ringdev_lock);
    ret=-EFAULT;
    if(ringdev_len + count < sizeof(ringdev_buf)) {
        if (copy_from_user(ringdev_buf+ringdev_len, buf, count)==0) {
            ringdev_len=ringdev_len+count;
            ret=count;
            wake_up_interruptible(&head);
            goto out_unlock;
        }
    } else {
       ret=-ENOSPC;
    }
    out_unlock:
    mutex_unlock(&ringdev_lock);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Reading should copy to user the entire buffer to be read, not just one character. Also beware when you wait that the condition may still be unsatisfied after the wait; in that case you should return -EINTR. On the writing side things are actually looking alright

Comment: Also we expect 1234\n5\n to be the content after the echo commands (cat would show 1234 and 5 on separate lines)

Comment: @PaulStelian Post an answer :p.

Comment: @Stargateur I will only post as answer what definitely or most likely is a problem, not guesses (even if they are educated guesses)

Comment: On read you return length on erroneous case?!

Answer (score 1):

Calling of copy_to_user(buf, ringdev_buf,1) causes 1 byte copy from ringdev_buf to buf, so its right, if you want copy entire buffer to userspace, you have to change it to copy_to_user(buf, ringdev_buf, ringdev_len)

Comment: I have changed it but I still get:

Comment: I have changed it but I still get only the last echo response

Comment: it should be opy_to_user(buf, ringdev_buf, ringdev_len) not opy_to_user(buf, ringdev_buf, 4096)

Comment: Yes in my code i have got copy_to_user(buf,ringdev_buf,ringdev_len) and the problem is still  happening. I realy don't know why it happen

Comment: the return value of read function is incorrect in case of successful read

Comment: I have changed  it. but still i only get the last echo response :;

Comment: i think the problem is on rest of the code, edit your question and include them

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (copy_to_user(buf, ringdev_buf,ringdev_len))
```

should be:

```
 if (copy_to_user(buf, ringdev_buf,ringdev_len)==0)
```

additionally, I  didn't make correctly the char device.  But thank you for help :). If someone needs I can post here my write/read  function on a cyclic buffer, where every think works correctly.